# Extract specific components from the response of REST API called via oracle procedure

Tags: plsql

I have created a oracle procedure to call a rest api of Application/JSON. Now that I am able to get response from the rest api, but I need to extract specific components from the response in the oracle procedure.

I need to extract ""resultCode": "EIL000"" and ""resultMsg": "Success" from the response.
please find below response:

{"resultHeader": {
"requestId": "1234",
"correlationId": "4544352435",
"timestamp": "2021-02-09 20:21:42",
"resultCode": "EIL000",
"resultMsg": "Success"
}}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json table](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm) for this

```
with data(json) as (
 select q'~{"resultHeader": { "requestId": "1234", "correlationId": "4544352435", "timestamp": "2021-02-09 20:21:42", "resultCode": "EIL000", "resultMsg": "Success" }}~' from dual union all
 select q'~{"resultHeader": { "requestId": "2345", "correlationId": "4544359915", "timestamp": "2021-02-09 21:21:42", "resultCode": "EIL001", "resultMsg": "Failure" }}~' from dual
)
select parsed_data.*
from data
, json_table(
    data.json, '$.resultHeader'
    columns (
      request_id number        path '$.requestId'
    , resul_code varchar2(20)  path '$.resultCode'
    , result_msg varchar2(100) path '$.resultMsg'
    )
  ) parsed_data
;
```

If you need to process a single JSON object and you have it stored in PL/SQL variable (as in `json_data` below), you can use:

```
declare 
  jo json_object_t;
  json_data varchar2(4000);
  result_code varchar2(20);
  result_msg varchar2(100);
begin
  json_data := q'~{"resultHeader": { "requestId": "1234", "correlationId": "4544352435", "timestamp": "2021-02-09 20:21:42", "resultCode": "EIL000", "resultMsg": "Success" }}~';
  
  jo := json_object_t.parse(json_data);
  jo := jo.get_object('resultHeader'); -- drill down into the resultHeader object
  
  result_code := jo.get_string('resultCode');
  result_msg := jo.get_string('resultMsg');
end;
/
```

Comment: please suggest me if the data is in buffer variable of varchar2(4000), how can I use the above mention one

 begin
    loop
      utl_http.read_line(res, buffer);
      dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
    end loop;
    utl_http.end_response(res);

Comment: I've updated the answer with PL/SQL approach. Your `buffer` would equal `json_data` in the answer